# Cannot SSH nor connect to public IP of Amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, ssh, ec2-ami

I had a site running fine on an ec2 instance a few months ago.  I decided recently to begin work on that site and I can no longer ssh into the instance.  I would get a series of timeouts or connection refusals with debug logs like

> /Users/alexanderbollbach/Dropbox/projs/web/ABApp2/ec2 (master): ssh -vvv -i TestKeyPair.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-166-142-77.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
>   OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
>   debug2: resolving "ec2-54-166-142-77.compute-1.amazonaws.com/" port 22
>   debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
>   debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-166-142-77.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ [92.242.140.21] port 22.
>   debug1: connect to address 92.242.140.21 port 22: Connection refused
>   ssh: connect to host ec2-54-166-142-77.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ port 22: Connection refused

I looked the problem up and noticed most similar issues were resolved by adding inbound traffic security rules but mine seem to be in order.

[image: inbound traffic rules]

I also read that instances can fail in some way so I restarted the instance.  At this point, I cannot ssh into the instance NOR can I even go to the public DNS or IP.

Can somebody help me solve this?

Comment: Are you able to **ping** the instance from your workstation(laptop/desktop)? if not Open ICMP rule in security group and try.

Comment: I winded up creating a new instance.  This fixed the problem.  I don't know what the bad state of the original problematic one was.  I never did the ping test but the ssh was hanging on some type of error that seemed internal to the instance so my guess is it wasn't tcp connection (or whatever that is)